# Why is the top margin of headings missing in Rich Text Fields?

Tags: slds, knowledge, richtextarea

When I add headings to a **Rich Text Field** on an **Article**, I'm seeing some strange behavior.

In the HTML Editor, I see an even top & bottom margin (see attached screenshot).  But when I save the document, the top margin is missing on the record itself (see attached screenshot).

[image]

What can I do to restore the top margin on those headings?

If they can't be restored, is my only option to add an SLDS Class to the heading via the Source?  This seems like an awful hack for something that seems to be a Salesforce error.

**Update**: Here is a screenshot of the HTML Source of the Article to see if sparks any ideas.  But it does seem pretty clean to me.

[image]

Comment: What does the source in the knowledge answer editor show (`Source` button)?

Comment: Hey @KrisGoncalves.  I added a screenshot of it to the question above.  I think the source looks pretty clean to me.

Answer (score 0):

I filed a ticket with Salesforce support.  They currently recommend using line breaks to fix the layout issue.  It's not a great solution, but at least its something.